# Scaffolding of Enum as a Select Control but no values are seen

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to populate the select control with the values of the `CivilStatus` enum:

I have these models:

```
public class MissionPartner
{
    [Key]
    public int ParnterId { get; set; }       
    public CivilStatus MaritalStatus{ get; set; }       
}

public enum CivilStatus
{
    Single,
    Married
}
```

And I am using this code in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="MaritalStatus" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="MaritalStatus" class="form-control"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="MaritalStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Generated view:

[image]

As you can see, there are no values in the control.

Comment: There are no values because you need to pass `asp-items` to the `select` control.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Oh, should I pass them manually? I was expecting the scaffolding to do that. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template do the following (and adjust to your needs):

```
<select asp-for="MaritalStatus" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<CivilStatus>()">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is scheduled to be fixed in .NET 8:
https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1885